# .remove() is not working while using in .on() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

.remove() is not able to remove the matched element from the DOM, but elements are present in DOM.

```
        var $closeIcon = $("<i class='fa fa-times pull-right'></i>");

        $closeIcon.on("click", function () {
            $blackOverlay.remove();
            $(".tour-block").remove();
        });
```

$blackOverlay is being removed, but it is not removing '.tour-block' matched element in the DOM.

```
var $blackOverlay = $("<div class='black-overlay'></div>");

$("body").prepend($blackOverlay);
```

NOTE: ".tour-block" elements are prepended elements on click.

```
var $Block = $("<div class='tour-block requests'></div>");

$target.prepend($Block);
```

Comment: Please include your HTML structure, and describe what exactly is `$blackOverlay`

Comment: You should run `console.log($(".tour-block"));` inside of your event handling function to ensure it's matching something.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: make a console.log on $('.tour-block'), i think it has not the context you wish

Comment: Try replacing `$closeIcon.on("click", function () {` with `$('.tour-block').on("click", '.fa-times', function () {`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown much of your codebase but I'll try my best to help.

If no errors have popped up during runtime, my diagnosis is that the '.tour-block' elements don't exist when `$(".tour-block").remove()` statement is executed. Note that most of Jquery's operations don't throw errors when performed on no matched elements.

Check if the '.tour-block' elements actually exist during that moment. Use something like this and inspect the elements matched.

```
console.log($('.tour-block'));
```

Make sure you are executing after the document is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // todo
});
```